# How can Aragorn fight with a broken sword?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

In the book, Aragorn has Anduril in his scabbard, but it is broken, as he shows
Sam. How could he defend himself in the wild? Is there any reference from LOTR or HoME?

Comment: This (in my probably misguided opinion) is something handled well in the movies. In the books, I guess no one -- man or beast -- wanted to fight him, because a dude who carries a broken sword must be badass indeed.

Comment: I'd just assume that he doesn't always carry it with him, and the time he met the Hobbits in Bree was an exception rather than the norm.  I'd have a hard time imagining him bringing it to Gondor during his time there as Thorongil, for example: one would expect that it would have almost certainly been recognised for what it was.

Comment: @mh01 But he had extra need to fight while he was with the Ringbearer.

Comment: Quite true; none of it really adds up, so hence a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @mh01 Maybe Tolkien just overlooked it, or maybe Aragorn had a bow of a dagger. But I want *quotes*!

Comment: IIRC, there was *part* of a blade there, probably still pretty sharp. Might have been able to use it somewhat

Comment: @SSumner One foot long blade?

Comment: While another weapon isn't mentioned, that doesn't mean he didn't carry one. Nowhere in the books is it mentioned that Aragorn/Strider actually used the sword that was broken before it was reforged. Ergo, it's quite possible he had other weapons and used those. Someone traveling the wilds would have a bow, dagger, and likely an axe for example for hunting, chopping wood, cleaning game, etc..

Comment: @jwenting and he had torches if needed (e.g. to fight the Nazghul), but I want some text.

Comment: @MadTux as I said, just because there is no text doesn't mean there is no weapon. And there's no text showing him to be using Narsil as a weapon either before it was reforged and renamed Anduril. I seriously doubt it'd be balanced enough to be effective except maybe to cut a side of meat from an animal killed using something else.

Comment: @jwenting I still want canon text. Not speculation. Waaaaah! (I'll look in HoME right now)

Comment: @MadTux - I don't recall how long it was. It was likely sharp enough to still cut, if not useable to stab

Comment: It's worth pointing out, OP, that Narsil was the name of the sword that was broken. It was named Anduril after it was reforged.

Comment: @MadTux - Your question contains an error- before it was reforged, the sword was called Narsil;  it didn't become known as Andúril until it was reforged.

Comment: For most cases, Aragorn could probably either avoid any confrontation or intimidate down most people he would encounter. Plus, it's never said he didn't have other gear, it's just in the Weathertop confrontation he didn't have anything that would be effective against the Nazgul.

Answer (score 20):

Throughout the Lord of the Rings, willpower and lineage are far more powerful forces than mere arms.  The primary weapons of the Nazgul are not their swords (dangerous though they are) but their voices.  Sauron doesn't ever actually do *anything* in LotR, save command legions of followers and cause his enemies to quail in fear (mostly indirectly via the Nazgul).  The Dead strike their enemies with madness, not with weapons.  The siege at Helm's Deep was broken by the dawn and the appearance of Gandalf the White, not because the orcs were outmatched by Erkenbrand's newly-arrived forces.  Although brute force does play some role (in destroying Isengard, in taking down the gate at Gondor, in the destruction of the balrog, etc.), it is usually secondary.

So I think it is consistent for Aragorn to routinely travel without any weapon at all, or with only a broken weapon, except in times of war.  He commands respect--from Barliman, for example--even when being dismissed as a queer ranger, and from animals (the horse Hasufel in Rohan, for instance).  In the wild, his stature as the heir of Gondor, and his long years of travel as a ranger, are probably enough (given that he exists in Middle Earth).

Comment: How does he hunt deer?

Comment: @MadTux - What evidence is there that he does hunt deer most of the time?

Comment: He still needs to fight – a ranger just *doesn't* go unarmed. He might be killed by an occasional orc that way.

Comment: @MadTux - My point is that in Middle Earth, _no, he would not_.  A ranger in the wild, caught unawares by a brutish orc?  Unlikely.  If he was, and not ambushed, are you so skeptical of Aragorn's ability to use a branch to turn aside an orc-weapon and cast down the orc (who would at least flee)?  If he were ambushed, would a sword really save him?  The laws of Middle Earth don't work the same way as ours, or all the heroes (and probably all of Gondor) would simply think, "Oh, screechy wailing, thanks for letting us know you're around, Nazgul!"  But sure, pick up a sword when hunting orcs.

Comment: @MadTux Few people, if any, hunt deer with swords, broken or otherwise.  If he could get close enough to a deer for a sword to be effective, I imagine he could just as easily leap on its back and break its neck.

Comment: @Beofett Bad example, I guess.

Comment: @MadTux Yeah, but I guess I should also add that I get your point.  He's got to have *something*, even if it is just a long belt knife.

Comment: +1 This answer is simply beautiful. The _narrative world_ of LotR simply doesn't work like ours. It's mythical. Ancient heroes and weapons of yore are terrible and powerful because... well, pretty much because the lore of the world says so.

Comment: @RexKerr - the other Rangers carry weapons, and we are led to believe that Aragorn has been in many skirmishes, and at least a few battles.  A combatant in a battle is useless if he is unarmed, unless everyone else is also unarmed.  He might not hunt deer *most of the time*, but he does say that he has "some skill as a hunter" or something like that, shortly after we meet him.  However, he would presumably use a bow for that, and I seem to remember him having one of those.

Comment: @RexKerr - in our world, and presumably in Tolkien's as well, you don't become an expert swordsman overnight.  It takes lots of practice.  He couldn't do his job without some kind of weapon.

Comment: @WadCheber - Just because you need a weapon when you go to war it does not follow that you're going to tromp about in the wild carrying a sword.  Of course Aragorn would have had a sword when he was expecting battle, and would have used both real and training weapons when training.  It doesn't follow that he carries one all the time, not when, as I said, willpower and lineage are so effective.

Comment: @RexKerr - The problem with that argument is that he DID carry a sword around with him in the wild, but it was a broken sword and therefore simply useless extra weight.  We don't know if he always carried it around, of course (he might have brought it to Bree because he knew he would be in Rivendell soon and would need to have it reforged), but we also don't know for sure that he didn't always carry it with him..

Comment: @WadCheber - Unless you know for certain that Aragorn is doing something weird (like not carry a functional sword), isn't it safe to assume he has some reasonable reason for it (i.e. he is _precisely_ carrying his heirloom sword because he knows he's going to Rivendell next, and that it is time for the sword that was broken to be reforged, etc. etc.).

Comment: @RexKerr - I'm not sure what you mean.  Aragorn definitely IS carrying a broken and unusable sword when he meets Frodo, Sam, Merry and Pippin.  He definitely is NOT carrying a second, intact, useable sword.  If you consider that "weird", then he is doing something weird.  If this is unreasonable, then the only reasonable explanation is that he knows he is headed to Rivendell, where the sword will be remade.  I have no way of knowing if that is why he is carrying a broken sword, but it would make sense, on a purely speculative basis.

Comment: @RexKerr But if I recall correctly, he might have been carrying a bow as well, and I am certain that he has some other weapons- at least one dagger, possibly a small knife, and perhaps something else as well.  To be sure of all this, I would have to go back and read the relevant chapters again, but I don't have the time or the inclination to do so right now.

Comment: His "broken sword" still had a foot of blade above the hilt. It may not be a full sword, but not exactly useless as a weapon, either.

Answer (score 13):

He carries the broken sword as an heirloom of his House not as a weapon. And just because his sword is broken it doesn't necessarily mean he has no other weapons. He probably came to Bree from Rivendell and was travelling light as the lands aren't particularly dangerous for a Ranger and he plans on returning before his next journey. He also knows weapons are no use against The Nine anyway.

Comment: He wields two torches fighting the Nazgul at Weathertop, and that seems to work.

Comment: He definitely doesn't have a second weapon; see Tolkien's letter to Zimmerman: "Aragorn would not "whip out a sword"; it was broken, after all" - http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Letter_210

Comment: @user8719 That implies he definitely doesn't have a second *sword* but he could have had other weapons. A knife would seem essential for a Ranger.

Answer (score 13):

> "There is food in the wild," Strider said, "berry, root, and herb; and I have some skill as a hunter at need. You need not be afraid of starving before winter comes. But gathering and catching food is long and weary work, and we need haste."
>   The Fellowship of the Ring

Remember that Aragorn has journeyed long in the wilderness and is able to procure his own food. Hunting requires at least a good-sized utility knife for skinning, cutting rope for trap-making, and a ton of other things. No good hunter/tracker would journey without a decent knife. So we know that Aragorn at least has one of those, maybe several, that he could defend himself with at a pinch.

I also think hunting would require perhaps a small bow/arrow, not for formal archery but close-range shots. Indeed, the LOTR movies portray Aragorn as having a small bow and a hunting knife as well, which you can see Viggo Mortensen sharpening during some scenes.

It always did seem odd to me that Aragorn should carry around the shards of Narsil, a precious and ancient relic of his house, on his long journeys in the wild. What if he lost it? What if it was stolen? And it clearly would be useless as a sword.

I speculate that he only sometimes carried it around on short journeys, and not all the time. He probably carried a proper sword at other times if he felt he would need it. Just because he had Narsil on him at the time he met up with Frodo doesn't mean he had carried it around always for his whole life.

Comment: Indeed, he may have brought it with him precisely as proof that he is Strider, given that the blade is mentioned in Gandalf's letter.

Comment: @chepner - In advance Aragorn didn't know about the letter, so he couldn't have brought the sword with him for that purpose. From _The Fellowship of the Ring,_ Book I, chapter 10, "Strider:" ‘Why didn’t you tell me [Frodo] that you were Gandalf ’s friend at once?’ he asked. ‘It would have saved time.’
‘Would it? Would any of you have believed me till now?’ said Strider. ‘**I knew nothing of this letter.**'

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that it was broken but still usuable?

Could it have just had the top 6 inches broken off or something?  That would mean it is still a functional sword and also is the sword that is broken?

Comment: No, it broke a foot over the hilt. I can't remember where I read it, probably LOTR or unfinished tales.

Comment: @MadTux - It's in LotR when Sam is suspicious of "Strider": He drew out his sword, and they saw that the blade was indeed broken a foot below the hilt. ’Not much use is it Sam?’ said Strider. ’But the time is near when it shall be forged anew.’

Comment: Fair enough.  It would still be slight use in a fight but not really against another armed swordsman.  Certainly not something that you would want as your primary weapon

Comment: A foot of edge of a great sword that retained its edge makes a good knife.

Comment: This is the sword that cut the ring from Sauron’s hand. I think it’s safe to say it isn’t utterly useless.

Answer (score 0):

He has two swords; Narsil isn't reforged until later in the series, before then he uses his other sword. An example of him using the other sword was during the fight with the Uruk-hai next to the river at the end of movie/book one. Narsil resides in Rivendell and isn't delivered to him until later in the series after it is reforged into Anduril.

Comment: Narsil is reforged at Rivindell before the Fellowship leaves.

Comment: yes, as usual the movies corrupt the books here. But that doesn't detract from the fact that he'd have another weapon that's actually functional.

Comment: @Itchy - no, this is movie-nonsense.  Forget the movies.

Comment: Imho, this specific aspect is handled better by the movies. Why should anyone carry around a broken sword? It is not useful at all. Why didn't it get lost?